# Howto match many words and use this match in substitution

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I'm using the VS2012 replace feature to replace some text in the editor.

I want to replace `>OneWord</Label>` with `Content="OneWord" />`.

And I want to replace `>More than one word</Label>` with `Content="More than one word" />`.

At the moment I have Find what filled with

```
>(\w+|[^\S\r\n]+)</Label>
```

and Replace with filled with

```
 Content="$1" />
```

This works for the first case where only one word is used, but not for the second case.

If I use `>(\w+|[^\S\r\n]+)+</Label>` I get `Content="word" />` for the secod case.

How can I define my regular expressions to work in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your are matching either a sequence of word characters `\w+` **or** a sequence of whitespace `[^\S\r\n]+`.

To solve your problem, just move the quantifier and add another group:

```
>((\w|[^\S\r\n])+)</Label>
```

Your result is still in `$1`.